# How to configure nginx as a proxy for keycloak server using docker

Tags: docker, nginx, keycloak

I have used nginx and keycloak docker images and both the images are up and running fine individually.However i am having issues while making nginx as a reverse proxy for keycloak server.
Can i someone let me know what are exact configuration changes that need to be done to make it work.

Thanks

Comment: What are the configuration changes you have tried?

Comment: i have made below changes in the config. I have mapped 8087 port to my container. so i have made below changes to ngins config                                                                                                              
      location /auth {
      proxy_pass http://localhost/8087;

      proxy_http_version 1.1;

      proxy_set_header Host               $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  https;
}

Comment: Also i have set PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true in my keycloak server.

Comment: anything else that need to be done?

Comment: I have it running but instead of relying on `PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING` environment variable, I added a custom configuration file and made my custom docker build to replace the one it comes by default. However, you should explicitly describe the issues you're having, is the request reaching your nginx server? What do the logs tell you?